# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2047-10-23 23:29:24' for column 'date'

Tags: mysql

When I insert the date as '2019-10-10 00:00:00', my operation can be completed.
But when I inserted the date as '2047-10-23 23:29:24', my mysql reported an error.

```sql
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2047-10-23 23:29:24' for column 'date' at row 1
```

### mysql version:5.7.21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check your field's datatype. If its `timestamp` then update that to be a `datetime`

**From MySql Reference:
The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types**

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.